# Querying distinct values for an array per document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a bunch of documents, for example

{
items: [ObjectId1, ObjectId2, etc.]
}

How do I run a query to identify which documents have duplicates?  `.distinct` returns distinct values across the collection, but I want to be able to report on per document:

1. the length/size of `items`
2. the length/size of the unique/distinct `items`

essentially, to understand which documents have duplicates in the `items` array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation with [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator to have unique items in the set:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$items"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "items_cnt": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "unique_items": {
        "$addToSet": "$items"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "items_cnt": 1,
      "unique_items_cnt": {
        "$size": "$unique_items"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VtnHOqRqRs_)